# Alternative expression for the differential solid angle?

Tags: differential, angle

[Attached clipping from my lecture notes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8nMn.png)

In this expression for the differential solid angle element I don't quite see how:
$$
\sin\theta \, d\theta=d(\cos\theta)
$$
Why is it not:
$$
-\sin(\theta) \, d\theta=d(\cos\theta)
$$
since the derivative of $\cos$ is $-\sin$.

Comment: I suspect a tacit absolute value based on an idea that an angle is always positive. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed $-\sin(\theta)d\theta$, but you should also consider the integration limits. At $\theta=0$, $\cos(\theta)=1$, and at $\theta=\pi$, $\cos(\theta)=-1$. So
$$\int_0^\pi\sin(\theta)d\theta=\int_1^{-1}(-1)d(\cos \theta)=\int_{-1}^1d(\cos \theta)$$